# add QueryString to context.request

Tags: c#, .net, json, httpcontext

I have a POST call :

```
info = {"Name":"XX","Surname":"ZZZ","identityCode":"0434"}
```

I am reading info in JObject and I want to add the name and values to context

```
Myinfo = context.Request["info"]; // context is a HttpContext
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(Myinfo);
foreach (JProperty o in obj.Properties())
{
    string ke = o.Name.ToString();
    string va = o.Value.ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Add(ke, va);
}
string surname= context.Request.QueryString["Surname"];
```

This is an example to show what I want to do. because I need to read parameters as they are `GET`
but surname string is null after my foreach loop.

I need help to add keys and values in `info` to `context.Request` so that I can access them like  `context.Request["Name"]; context.Request["Surname"];` ...

Comment: Dumb question: is querystring  ever null or empty?

Comment: @AlexSuleap I updated my question it was a useless check